How to gather deletion timestamps for Instagram posts from exported data or APIs?
I am trying to find out when a specific Instagram post was deleted. I’ve already downloaded my Instagram data via the Data Download tool, but I couldn’t find any file (e.g., account_activity.json or media.json) that logs deletion timestamps. I also explored the Instagram Graph API, but it seems to only retrieve active posts.
Is there a way to retrieve deletion timestamps (either through the exported data or programmatically)? If not, are there other approaches (e.g., logs, APIs, or third-party tools) that can help?
Tools I’ve tried:

Instagram data export (downloaded all files).
Search using grep and other text editors.
Instagram Graph API endpoints (/me/media).

Any guidance or alternative methods would be appreciated.
